# How to make a Copper/Rose Gold smudge material?

Tags: materials

Help! How to make such material procedurally in cycles
[image]

Comment: Please read https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Maybe change the title to  "How to make a Copper/Rose Gold smudge material" So its more useful to others in the future

Comment: Did you tried something that comes close? Add details about what you tried, for others to see your current approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a simple principled shade.

Slide the metallic and specular (forgot to change specular) close to 1.

Choose a rose gold color and use a texture in your roughness. I put two options, a procedural way (noise texture stretched with mapping node) but I think an actual texture image looks better.

Use an HDRI so you get more realistic reflections.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

My attempt to make material like on the picture

[image: But material is absolutely different from the original photo, pitty(]

[image]
My node setup

Comment: Please do not just post an image of your nodes, and be done. Your answer would be so much more helpful if you explained what each part was doing. Worse you have node groups in there that we can not see. Finally with no explanation, the unused nodes look useless.